# Pandas drop_duplicates() hang in jupyter-notebook - way to improve drop_duplicates() performace?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[Edited] With suggestions from the comment session, currently I have narrowed down the problem to `drop_duplicates()`, which causes the function run forever. After I remove `drop_duplicates()`, the function can come to the step `df_output.to_csv()` within a short time, but stopped there. I suspect the duplicates cause the problem. Any pandas experts have any suggestion?

The funtion for create output looks like below:

```
def create_output(model, users_to_recommend, n_rec, print_csv=True):
    recomendation = model.recommend(users=users_to_recommend, k=n_rec)
    df_rec = recomendation.to_dataframe()
    df_rec['recommendedProducts'] = df_rec.groupby([user_id])[page_id] \
        .transform(lambda x: '|'.join(x.astype(str)))
    df_output = df_rec[['userID', 'recommendedProducts']].drop_duplicates() \
        .sort_values('userID').set_index('userID')

    if print_csv:
        df_output.to_csv('output/normdata_recommendation.csv')
        print("An output file can be found in 'output' folder with name 'normdata_recommendation.csv'")
    return df_output
```

Output while calling the function:

```
recommendations finished on 1000/617256 queries. users per second: 263089
recommendations finished on 2000/617256 queries. users per second: 179340
recommendations finished on 3000/617256 queries. users per second: 152447
.
.
.
recommendations finished on 615000/617256 queries. users per second: 105123
recommendations finished on 616000/617256 queries. users per second: 104996
recommendations finished on 617000/617256 queries. users per second: 104910
```

function calls to create output:

```
# constant variables to define field names include:
user_id = 'userID'
page_id = 'pageID'
users_to_recommend = list(page_usage[user_id])
n_rec = 10 # number of items to recommend
n_display = 30 # to display the first few rows in an output dataset

name = 'popularity' # popularity model chosen
target = 'scaled_visit_freq'

popularity = model(train_data_norm, name, user_id, page_id, target, users_to_recommend, n_rec, n_display)

df_output = create_output(popularity, users_to_recommend, n_rec, print_csv=True)
```

The model function returns a chosen model with Turicreate, using that model perform training and it can be performed successfully. Output for the model function:

```
Preparing data set.
    Data has 20799 observations with 1138 users and 511 items.
    Data prepared in: 0.06968s
20799 observations to process; with 511 unique items.
recommendations finished on 1000/617256 queries. users per second: 270490
recommendations finished on 2000/617256 queries. users per second: 244499
.
.
.
recommendations finished on 615000/617256 queries. users per second: 108578
recommendations finished on 616000/617256 queries. users per second: 108591
recommendations finished on 617000/617256 queries. users per second: 108611
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199471/discussion-on-question-by-sylvia-pandas-drop-duplicates-hang-in-jupyter-notebo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soloved it by adding `drop_duplicates()` right after `df_rec = recomendation.to_dataframe()`. This will substantially reduce the computing requirement.

For whoever might find these pieces of codes useful, especially for large datasets, remember to change that line to `df_rec = recomendation.to_dataframe().drop_duplicates()`